# Backbone/Underscore Template -- when rendering why call toJSON?

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

When using backbone.js and the companion templating engine in underscore, I've noticed that most examples call `model.ToJSON()` when rendering instead of just passing `model`.   I understand that my template would have to modify how it retrieves data.

I'm wondering why & what benefit do we get from toJSON()?

**Typical Example**

In the typical example `model.toJSON()` is called when rendering. Note, for the sake of brevity, i put the template in as a string literal.

```
ToDoItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
   /* other viewey stuff */
   template : _.template( '<li><%=ToDoNote%></li>'),
   render   : function () {    
                   var out=  this.template(this.model.toJSON()); //<--JSON
                    $(this.el).html( out) }
                    return this;
                 }
 }); //end view
```

**An Alternate Method**

I dug through the backbone 0.9.2 & underscore 1.3.3 code.  In backbone, noticed that `model.toJSON()` does the following: `_.clone(this.attributes)`.  Inside the template rendering engine, my compiled template names the passed-data *obj*.

After seeing those snippets, I realized that cloning the attributes isn't necessary.  Instead, I can directly pass in my model (albeit, with some syntax changes in the template).  Something like ...

```
ToDoItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
   /* other viewey stuff */
   template : _.template( '<li><%=obj.get('ToDoNote')%></li>'), //<--notice GET()
   render   : function () {    
                   var out=  this.template(this.model);  //<-- look ma no json
                   $(this.el).html( result ) }
                   return this;
                 }
 }); //end view
```

Looking at the two examples, the only reasons I can come up with to call toJSON are :

- protect model data from a nefarious view
- the view locally modifies data (not a good idea in my opinion),
- view needs to access values using array/string syntax(  `obj[ namepart + someindex]`)

My question boils down to : why would I call `toJSON()` and take the hit for cloning the properties, rather than just use get() in my templates?

Comment: "the hit for cloning"? You think that calling `get` is free?

Comment: @muistooshort -- Free? no. `Get()` does   `return this.attributes[attr];`.  So is an array lookup faster than an array clone?  Yes--from both a resource & time aspect, but that misses my point.  Calling `toJSON()` is clearly built into the backbone communities collective thinking. I'm curious why.

Comment: "Repeated function calls and object accesses" versus "one clone and repeated object accesses" and I don't see any benchmark results so your *Yes* is merely opinion (just like all the answers are going to be, hence the "not constructive" vote). Not every view is going to be a direct mapping of a model or collection, `toJSON` is more flexible and reduces the noise in your template.

Comment: Sorry you seem angry about this. Your reason about "not necessarily direct mappings" is a good constructive answer.

Comment: I'm not angry, comments need to be brief and I don't think this sort of discussion belongs here, nothing personal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe the following makes sense:

1. Interpolating instead of evaluating is a big cost to take. So your version of the template *is* actually a lot slower than calling `toJSon()` and using evalution.
2. Logic belongs to views not templates. Introducing js code (and the need for interpolation) in templates should only be done if necessary.
3. One could argue that you should be passing `model.attributes` instead of `model.toJSON()` avoiding the clone. I guess the reason for not doing so is to avoid allowing the template to change the model's attributes. In addition, you might typically want to augment the result of `model.toJSON()` with other things, which obviously you don't want to do on the `model.attributes`

Comment: Well said. Makes a lot of sense.

Comment: It should be noted that using `model.toJSON()` is advised against for views... it is for serializing the model for syncing, not rendering. You should pass `model.attributes` as you suggested. https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2134

Comment: Even using `toJSON()` or `_.clone()` may not entirely prevent the template from changing the model's attributes because the clone method creates "a shallow-copied clone of the object. Any nested objects or arrays will be copied by reference, not duplicated." (http://underscorejs.org/#clone) So, I recommend using `model.attributes`, but caution that you shouldn't be making changes to the model from the template in any case.

Answer (score 2):

A likely reason is because the developers of Backbone.js have allowed you to use any templating engine you desire, and many templating engines work off of simple javascript objects, *not* Backbone Models.

Comment: Good point. Although, I'm specifically talking about why/why-not to chose this strategy *for an underscore template*.